# Excel Formula to Power Bi Query

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I need to converter this formula to powerbi query, please help me

```
=SUMIFS(BIM!J2:J1633,BIM!H2:H1633,'BIM-02'!F2,BIM!D2:D1633,'BIM-02'!B2)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is an aggregation. You have to solve this in PowerPivot (DAX), not PowerQuery (M). The equivalent to Excel's SUMIFS is CALCULATE. So you need to do something along these lines:

```
Sum J on Condition = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM( JColumn ),
    AND (
        HColumn = F2,
        DColumn = B2
    )
)
```

However, you have to prepare your data model in PowerQuery in advance, since PowerBI doesn't have the concept of a "first row".